# Change keyframe interval

Tags: ffmpeg, css-animations

How do I set the keyframe interval to 5 seconds using FFmpeg?

Answer (score 38):

You'll need to reencode. Set x264's keyint parameter to 5*fps and disable scenecut. If your fps is 24 for example :

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=120:scenecut=0 -acodec copy out.mp4
```

This is obviously not optimal for quality but it'll match your demand.

Edited to change `no-scenecut` to `scenecut=0`, as per sigh-boy suggestion.

Comment: It hurts either the quality or the bitrate. Smart encorders will place keyframes when there is a scenecut so that future frames can have a clean reference. If you force the interval, keyframes won't be optimal at all for future frames and this will hurt the stream overall.

Comment: I'm curious since the link in sigh-boy's answer says: _Setting scenecut to 0 is equivalent to setting --no-scenecut._

Answer (score 27):

Sigh.

The misinformation regarding the [`no-scenecut`](http://www.chaneru.com/Roku/HLS/X264_Settings.htm#no-scenecut) option has been going on for longer than I can remember. Never enter a value for `no-scenecut`.

A link to documentation can be found [here](http://www.chaneru.com/Roku/HLS/X264_Settings.htm).

For FFmpeg you need to use the following two switches:

`-g 120` will define a GOP of 120 frames to create a five second GOP for 23.976fps content. This works in conjunction with the `no-scenecut` option.

`-x264-params no-scenecut=1` (formerly `-x264opts no-scenecut`) will force keyframes to be created per the GOP value that FFmpeg uses. The default for `libx264` is to create a keyframe when it detects a scene change. If you inspect an output file using MediInfo without that option will see `scenecut=40`. When done properly that will be `scenecut=0`. If this option is not used then keyframes will be misaligned for ABR content and segment sizes will be unpredictable.

Do not take my word for it, please run the following under a bash shell where $inputfile is the name of the file you want to analyze. If you use the two switches shown above then you will see a very even cadence of keyframes dump to the command prompt.

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries \
  frame=pict_type -of csv $inputfile | grep -n I | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

You can also reference an article that I wrote regarding how to create proper ABR frame aligned content [here](https://videoblerg.wordpress.com/2016/08/16/how-to-create-abr-content-with-ffmpeg-in-one-pass/).

Comment: For full accuracy, you should use `frame=key_frame`. It's possible to have I-frames which aren't keyframes.

Comment: @Gyan how is it possible?