# Cannot change video keyframe interval to be 1 using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, keyframe, ffprobe

I am trying to change a video's **keyframe interval to be 1** following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979714/how-to-change-keyframe-interval-in-ffmpeg) and using the command

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=30:no-scenecut -acodec copy out.mp4
```

as indicated in the first answer. I wrote `keyint=30` as my video's `fps` is `30`, so `1*30=30`. However, only the first frame's keyframe is `1`, and all the rest remain `0` (as before the above command), as shown by the command `ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -show_frames out.mp4` :

```
...
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=0
pkt_pts_time=0.000000
pkt_dts=0
pkt_dts_time=0.000000
best_effort_timestamp=0
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.000000
pkt_duration=512
pkt_duration_time=0.033333
pkt_pos=48
pkt_size=18693
width=560
height=320
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=0
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=0
pkt_pts=512
pkt_pts_time=0.033333
pkt_dts=512
pkt_dts_time=0.033333
best_effort_timestamp=512
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.033333
pkt_duration=512
pkt_duration_time=0.033333
pkt_pos=21764
pkt_size=199
width=560
height=320
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
pict_type=B
coded_picture_number=3
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
[/FRAME]
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your command is correct: it outputs an I-frame each second or 30 frames. If you want an I-frame only output then you need to set `keyint` to 1 not 30.

Comment: @aergistal Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but again only the first frame has `keyframe = 1`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I achieved what I wanted with the command :

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -qscale 0 -g 1 outputFile.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks. This reduces video quality , though. Is this inherent to using more keyframes?

Comment: @user1323995 Using a keyframe interval of 1 is equivalent to encoding images individually. This means that instead of the compression ratio for videos (e.g., 1:100), you end up with the compression ratio for images (e.g., 1:10)... which is a 10x increase in bitrate. To compensate for this massive increase in bitrate, the quality might end up being reduced instead by e.g. 10 dB PSNR.